Identify shrouded header with ~2.5 mm pitch



The pitch appears to be ~2.5 mm


What does this mate with? is the mate just a 0.1 inch pitch pin header?  Does it lock into place or just friction fit?  can you provide picture of the mating side?  See if you can confirm if the pin spacing is 2.0mm or 0.1 inch, that will help narrow the search.  How large (AWG or mm diameter) are the wires that go into this connector?

Added a picture with the 4 wire that went into it and what it mates with. It looks like it kind of locks into place with the fins on the side

@greybeard easily addressed, see edit.

Why is there a different second connector in the last added photo?  Please don't confuse me, the one on the right with black/yellow/white/red wires is not the same connector as you showed originally. Looks like smaller pitch, probably 2.0mm (maybe JST PH series as @kruemi suggested), but again not what was originally asked for.  I spend a lot of time tracking down that first connector.

Sorry. The second connector(one with wire connected is a comparison. That connector is a 2mm jst. The one I need help identifying has no wires. Thank you!

Hard to confirm futher without more exact measurement and pictures, but I suspect the plug is Würth Elektronik WR-WTB 2.50 mm “J” Type Female Terminal Housing, 4-position version would be MPN 688004113322 (datasheet with details).  You also need the special crimps for end of wires MPN 68800113722 which click into the housing to build, but then you'd need their special crimper tool MPN 600620230220, which all sounds good until you realize the crimper would cost $350 USD.  But Würth does offer pre-crimped wires, with the heavier wire 22AWG being MPN 688188122030, which would be the easiest way to construct and just splice to the existing wires.  I found the connectors and crimps are available on some popular electronics component distributor websites for under $1 (not allowed to recommend here, shipping will cost way more than the connector parts), but I wasn't able to find the pre-crimped wires at my favorite US vendors.   You could try to crimp yourself without the special crimper tool but might take a few tries to get the right finished shape to fit inside the plug housing. When purchasing be careful to verify exact part number on the manufacture's website, because the name "WR-WTB" covers many different connectors sizes that are not all compatible.
Addition - while looking at @Davide Andrea answer and his website for this category of connector, I found that JST has a compatible insulation displacement connector (IDC) plug called the HR IDC series 2.5mm plugs that appears to be a viable replacement of OP damaged connector (plug compatible with EH series). IDC doesn't require any crimp construction, but instead has method to squeeze wire into a built-in contact and pierce the insulation.  This would be good candidate for a repair build (no special crimp tool required).  There are different variants for different wire size.  Advise you buy extra spares if you try this to practice with different IDC insertion techniques/tools.

four position 28 AWG JST MPN 04HR-8M-P-N
four position 26 AWG, JST MPN 04HR-6S-P-N  (in stock US)
four position 24 AWG, JST MPN 04HR-4K-P-N


My Identiconn utility identified that as a JST EH.
Specifically:

Female plug housing: EHR-4
Male PCB header: B4B-EH-A


{Source: Digikey}

{Source: Digikey}

I agree this JST EH series is also a potential match, and the Würth Elektronik WR-WTB 2.50 mm “J” Type series (see my answer) have identical dimensions to within tolerance, and likely intended to be cross-compatible.   The JST female plug should have molded lettering "H JST" and pin numbers on the side   Interestingly, using @Davide Andrea Identiconn website, just discovered that JST HR plug is also compatible with EH header, which is insulation displacement design that DOES NOT require crimps, https://www.jst.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/eHR-IDC-new.pdf, different MPN for each wire size.

Davide Andrea - thanks for your great connectorbook.com identiconn.  Did you expand this class on your website recently?  I'm confident I looked at your website during my search for this question and found a reference to Würth Elektronik but was their 646 2.5mm family, but then I stumbled onto the "J" type (WR-WTB 688 family) while on their website. Now I see you have that exact family also listed under Rectangular > GP > Low-Profile > LP 2.5mm, adjacent to this JST EH family.  Did I somehow just miss that on your website while searching, or have you been busy growing the site?

@BK303 - I made a major revision to the software and user interface in July. In particular, the filter is more advanced. Every week I add more families to the database. Right now I am adding board-to-board connector families from Chinese manufacturers.
